# How to store multiple items in IDictionary?

Tags: c#

I have this `IDictionary` declaration: `IDictionary<string, string> trace;`

Inside of it I want save a list of element returned by a json deserialization, actually I do this like:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

foreach (var item in obj)
{
    trace["date"] = item.trace.details.date; 
    trace["type"] = item.trace.details.type;

    foreach (var trace in item.trace.context.context)
    {
          trace["context"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trace);
    }
}
```

Now this code working good but save only the last item of the iteration, this 'cause when I iterate over the item the `date, type etc...` are replaced, but I want store the item not replace it in each new iteration.
How can do this with `IDictionary`?

**Note that:** `trace.x` is the name of the class that deserialize the json.

*Further question*: Maybe the use of IDictionary is not a good idea for achieve this?

Comment: You may find `Lookup` being an alternative `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx`

Comment: You need unique keys for each `item` and again for each `trace`.  Or you can do `IDictionary<string, List<string>>` instead.  Or really create a custom class that has a date and type parameter and the context as a list and use that as your dictionaries value type.

Comment: @juharr I already tried with it but I got this message: Implicit cast 'string' in `System.Collection.Generic.List<string>`

Comment: Your motivation to store this in a dictionary seems to be because you *want* to use a dictionary here, not because you *need* to use one. What is your actual goal with that data?

Comment: @Sandokan You'd need to change more than the type, you'd also have to make changes to your code for that to work.

Comment: @poke my goal is create an object that I can easy read with `object_name["date"][0]` where 0 rapresent the index of the item stored inside the IDictionary.

Comment: @Sandokan But you could just do `obj[0].trace.details.date` instead.

Comment: @juharr the code that I've shown just demonstrate how I add the element (actually) in the IDictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you'd be better off using a dedicated class, something like this:

```
public class TraceInfo
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<string> ContextItems { get; set; }
}
```

Then for every value in `obj`, create a `TraceInfo` object using `new TraceInfo()` and set its properties.

You can then store them in a `List<TraceInfo>` or in a `Dictionary<string, TraceInfo>`, the choice is yours.