# Can't store multiple items in IDictionary

Tags: c#

I have created this `IDictionary`:

```
IDictionary<string, string> trace = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

my goal is use it for save the content of json deserialized. I save the content in the `IDictionary` like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

foreach (var item in obj)
{
      trace["date"] = item.trace.details.date;
      trace["type"] = item.trace.details.type;
}
```

now in the `obj` variable I have 180 elements, the foreach over all items available in obj. The problem is that in the `trace` dictionary for each iteration each `item` is replaced, so I get only the item of the last iteration. How can I save all items in the dictionary? 
A dictionary shouldn't push each item automatically in the next iteration, instead of replacing it?

Comment: this statement trace["date"] = "value" will replace the old value

Comment: @Santosh but I don't want replace the old value, I want store it.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. How do you want to retrieve values?

Comment: If you want multiple values for the same key, you should make the Dictionary's value a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: Your intent is not clear at all. Can you explain what you want to achieve? What is the purpose of storing those values in the dictionary?

Comment: Santosh's comment was an indication to _what **you** are doing_ is replacing it. I think he know's that you want to add more values.

Comment: @VisualVincent I already tried, but I get cast exception on the foreach, in particular on `item.trace.details.date` that is a string. @Tim S. I want save all date values inside the key `date`. So for example, will be 100 records `date`.

Comment: @Sandokan use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead.

Comment: If you use a `List<string>` as value you would of course have to do this: `trace["date"].Add(item.trace.details.date);`

Comment: This looks a lot like your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576783/how-to-store-multiple-items-in-idictionary) where you accepted an answer.  What's changed?

Comment: @juharr Nope, the question is different. The previously question is about the join of two classes in one object, here is just the items of a foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Santosh pointed out, this is expected behavior. You could instead use a `List<Dictionary<String,String>>`

```
var traces = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();    
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);
foreach (var item in obj)
{
      var trace = new Dictionary<String,String>();
      trace["date"] = item.trace.details.date;
      trace["type"] = item.trace.details.type;
      ...
      traces.Add(trace);
}
```

Comment: I thinks this is not a good Idea, because that way you use a dictionary just for one entry. I think it should use KeyValuePair instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
IDictionary<string, string> trace = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();

trace.Add("date", new List<string>())
trace.Add("type", new List<string>())

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);

foreach (var item in obj)
{
   trace["date"].Add(item.trace.details.date)
   trace["type"].Add(item.trace.details.type)
}
```

Plz, feel free to improve this design.

Comment: you're adding date as key and value here. It should be `trace.Add("date", item.trace.details.date)`. It's also worth mentioning that the key can't be repeated, and it's exactly what he's trying to do.

Comment: Sory, I see now, I edited the answer, thx.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how dictionaries work in C#. As the name suggests it should be **one** key with **one** value. You don't have repeated entries in dictionaries, right?
What you're probably trying to do is add to values in each entry, so I'll suggest using `Tuple`, since I don't know the type of your json parsed data, I'll assume string for everything, but type really won't change anything here :

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
foreach (var item in obj)
{
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(item.trace.details.date, item.trace.details.type));
}
```

Now you'll reach each entry as `list[i].Item1` for a date on a given `i` index and `list[i].Item2` for a type on the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can do this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);
var traces = obj.Select(item => new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "date", item.trace.details.date },
    { "type", item.trace.details.type }
});
```

You will get an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>`. There isn't really a simpler way to do what you ask other than to use a collection of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a `Lookup<string, string>`, this is a one-to-many dictionary. You can create one using `ToLookup()` extension method:

```
var dates = obj.Select(o => new { Key = "date", Value = o.trace.details.date });
var types = obj.Select(o => new { Key = "type", Value = o.trace.details.type });

var lookUp = dates.Concat(types).ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```